# SSL.conf File not referencing .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

We're utilizing an htaccess file to pull CAC (smart card authentication) strings from users accessing our website. We're migrating from Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4 but still attempting to utilize the same htaccess files. Below is current ssl.conf with the 2.2 > 2.4 changes that I've applied. It's allowing me access to the site with my CAC string but I'm not in the htaccess file. It appears that it's bypassing the htacess file completely, even though I'm referencing it under each directory. I'm not sure if there's something simple that I'm missing and I'm looking for additional help regarding the configuration.

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Satisfy any
    Require all denied
    SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData +OptRenegotiate
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 10
    AuthName "**Please insert CAC card, restart your browser and try again**"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/conf/pki/httpd.passwd
    require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Comment: Why that may not please you, it is easier to put configuration directly in the main configuration files instead of `.htaccess`.  By doing so you gain simplicity, performance, security, etc. Otherwise double check the files permissions and enhance logging in Apache it should show maybe what is wrong.

Comment: This is a requirement by the customer to utilize the htaccess protocol. I enabled debug level logging and all I'm getting is "auth_basic:error user (my string) was not found referer: server.url/cssv2/customer-index.css"

Comment: "This is a requirement by the customer " I am sure curious about which constraints does that solve. Pushing logs to the extreme should show Apache looking for the file, or not. But anyway look after all AllowOverride statements in the given context, check all directories and files permissions and ownerships. You would not have any kind of problem like that when using the main configuration, but if your customer is happy to pay your time to find a solution just because he decided to create the problem with its requirements, that is indeed its complete right ;-)